# Add Additional Ips to my new Dedicated Server

Tags: centos, ip, dedicated-server

I'am not really into Commands and Dedciated server but i had to buy one recently with 5 usuable Ips and got the informations Bellow :

Usable IP Range: 142.54.190.234 - 142.54.190.238 
Gateway: 142.54.190.233 
Subnet Mask:255.255.255.248

How can add those Ips to the Main one via SSH ?? since i can connect to only the first one which is 142.54.190.234 knowing that im planing to Install Powermta on that server Btw the machine is runing centos 6

Comment: let me google it for you first link... : https://www.tecmint.com/create-multiple-ip-addresses-to-one-single-network-interface/

Comment: Thank you i will try my best with those command !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your default interface is eth0 then you'll be able to add the other ip address as aliases to the default interface (eth0) or whatever interface name you have there.

```
ifconfig eth0:0 142.54.190.235 netmask 255.255.255.248
ifconfig eth0:1 142.54.190.236 netmask 255.255.255.248
ifconfig eth0:2 142.54.190.237 netmask 255.255.255.248
ifconfig eth0:3 142.54.190.238 netmask 255.255.255.248
```

If you can add these in /etc/rc.local at the end just to be sure that in case of a restart/reboot of the server, these ips are added after boot.

There are other methods as well but this would be the easiest one and it does exactly what you need.